# How to upload files to LEMP stack on Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: webserver, cloud, azure-virtual-machine

I'm new to the whole cloud computing virtual machines thing, and I just started my free trial of Microsoft Azure. I'm interested in setting up a web server running Nginx to host some PHP pages that connect to a MySQL database. I just followed this [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-lemp-stack) on how to install a LEMP stack on a Linux virtual machine in Azure, but it doesn't give a whole lot of instruction after that. How do I upload my files to this newly created web server?

Comment: like you normally would, via ssh, or you can create an ftp on your server and use ftp to upload them. alternatively you can install some build agent on it (azure devops, jenkins, etc) and use that to deliver artifacts to the machine. lots of different ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many methods that you can upload files to your Azure Linux VM, Here are two options for you:

- [Move files to and from a Linux VM using SCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/copy-files-to-linux-vm-using-scp). In this way, you need an SCP client for your local computer. It is built on top of SSH and included in the default Bash shell of most Linux and Mac computers and some Windows shells.
- [Create An Azure File Share and mount to your Azure Linux VM](https://www.techcrumble.net/2019/02/how-to-create-an-azure-file-share-and-connect-to-a-linux-virtual-machine/). In this case, you will create a storage account, then [mount the Azure file share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux#mount-the-azure-file-share-on-demand-with-mount) on your Linux VM. It's better used for multiple clients to upload the files to Azure VMs.